# SQL Server 2012 command line parameters

Tags: sql-server, build-automation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 via some command line parameters. I have a simple form that has a few buttons to install various projects. One is to install a SQL Server with set names and security for the databases.  Here are the commands:

```
Private Sub btnSQLServer32_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSQLServer32.Click

    curPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(curDirectory, "SQLEXPR.exe")
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(curPath, "/QS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,TOOLS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=""True"" /INSTANCENAME=""TestDatabase"" SECURITYMODE=SQL" & _
                                         " /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"" /SAPWD=""********"" /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"" /SQLSVCPASSWORD=""********""" & _
                                         " /AGTSVCACCOUNT=""DomainName\UserName"" /AGTSVCPASSWORD=""*******"" /ASSVCACCOUNT=""DomainName\UserName"" /ASSVCPASSWORD=""********""" & _
                                         " /RSSVCACCOUNT=""DomainName\UserName"" /RSSVCPASSWORD=""*******"" /ISSVCACCOUNT=""NT Authority\Network Service"" /TCPENABLED=""1"" /NPENABLED=""1""")
```

The installation goes through and gets through installing setup files. When it begins to install, it stalls for a second, then exits without further warning.

My question is if there is any kind of error log that I can look at to see if it is one of my commands that are causing this? Does anyone see something that is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Look in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log

on the server you're doing the install on.

Comment: I did not have that file location on my particular machine

Comment: Does this mean that it didn't even get far enough to create that directory? By searching some more, looks like the logs in that folder are going to give me that answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't make this folder.

Comment: Trying running your setup.exe line from the command line. I think that's right, it's probably failing immediately, maybe because of a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also look in the windows event log, getting to it is OS specific, and I'd look namely under application.

Comment: start -> run -> "eventvwr". the app name is constant on all version of windows that have it.

Comment: I checked the application logs, but no reference of the install was anywhere. I created a custom view and looked for everything within the last hour, but didn't see anything listed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this for the last few hours, and I have discovered that SQLEXPR.exe is just a self-extracting container.

Execute SQLEXPR.exe /x to extract the contents. You will find a Setup.exe in that directory, where you will be able to pass your command-line arguments.

Now, you might be wondering how to script the bit where you are prompted to extract the contents, and I can't answer that yet. I'm having a go at this now, because I need to make a totally unattended installer. We may just end up mirroring a zipped copy of the extracted directory on our servers internally somewhere.